# Frustrating MySQL CREATE PROCEDURE error

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1064

Hopefully this is a nice quick one to resolve.

Here is my .sql file:

```
USE my_db;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE searchLocation(IN argQuery VARCHAR(32), IN argLimit INT)
BEGIN
  SELECT DISTINCT `suburb`, `postcode`
  FROM `location`
  WHERE `suburb` LIKE '%argQuery%'
  OR `postcode` LIKE 'argQuery%'
  LIMIT argLimit
  ;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

This is the output:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'argLimit
  ;
END' at line 8
```

So it appears to not like my parameter argLimit, but I can't work out why. I must be doing something silly.

I'm using MySQL 5.0.51.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LIMIT` must be a constant and cannot be parametrized inside a procedure or function in MySQL. However, it's possible to workaround this issue by using the [`PREPARE ... EXECUTE ... USING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) syntax.

It might end up looking somewhat like this:

```
...
SET @qry= argQuery;
SET @lmt= argLimit;

PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT ... LIKE ? ... LIKE ? ... LIMIT ?';
EXECUTE stmt USING @qry, @qry, @lmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: +1 for the diagnosis and workaround.  MySQL bug entry #11918 discusses just this peculiarity.

Comment: There is some discussion here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html in one of the comments about half way down the page marked  <strong>Posted by Marc Grue on June 24 2006 10:44am</strong>. I don't know how to link directly to the comment.

Comment: Thank you very much for the concise answer and work-around. Works a treat.

Answer (score 1):

The direct link to the [Marc Grue's comments](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#c7715).

[Trick to do this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#tableid) : 
Get the table id of the comment and create an anchor in the URL.